# Grails unit test controller field

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

Can someone tell me what the **controller** object in **controller**.searchService, **controller**.search() and **controller**.response.text.contains refers to? How is this controller object created and what is its purpose?

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
@TestFor(BookController)
@Mock(Book)
class BookControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test search"() {
        given:
        def searchMock = mockFor(SearchService)
        searchMock.demand.searchWeb { String q -> ['first result', 'second result'] }
        searchMock.demand.static.logResults { List results ->  }
        controller.searchService = searchMock.createMock()

        when:
        controller.search()

        then:
        controller.response.text.contains "Found 2 results"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller` is an instance of your Controller under test, specified in the `@TestFor` annotation. In this case, it is the `BookController`. It's created by Grails for you to use in your unit tests.

`controller.searchService` is the BookController's reference to the SearchService bean, which you mock in the given block.

`controller.search()` is calling the BookController's `search` action.

`controller.response.text` is the text output that the action writes to the response.

The [Testing docs](https://testing.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#unitTestingControllers) are for the newest, Trait-based, version of the testing framework but the concepts are still the same.